# Fazer chamada a comandos artisan direto do código

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Olá! Estou estudando laravel, e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer a chamada dos comandos artisan nos Controllers.
Exemplo: Quando o usuário clicar no botão ele executa um comando artisan, uma rotina ou algo relacionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou a versão do Laravel mas pelo menos na 5.1 tu pode usar a Facade do artisan

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

e dentro da função:

```
Artisan::call('down');
```

No exemplo que dei o Laravel foi colocado em modo manutenção.

Comment: Obrigado! Era exatamente o que procurava!